# Jquery Mobile.. Icons don't show up after use themeroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem when i use JQM themeroll  the icons at the end of the listview don't show up, i have been fighting for this all day and it is driving me insane.

Here is the link

http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1-theme/

As you can see on the right side there is just a gray circle, this is the standard swatch from themeroller as you can see, so i haven't changed anything, i also checked the paths to me images folder

If someone could point me in the right direction i would highly appreciative that

Dave

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file created by the Themeroller is located here: `/1-theme/css/`.

Which means that the images for jQuery Mobile need to be located here: `/1-theme/css/images/`.

Basically you need to upload the icon sprites to your own server, at the moment you are getting `404` errors associated with these files:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://your-site/css/custom.css"
>
> "NetworkError:
>   404 Not Found - http://your-site/css/style.css"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://your-site/1-theme/css/images/ajax-loader.png"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://your-site/1-theme/css/images/icons-18-white.png"

This is part of hosting your own jQuery Mobile CSS style-sheet, you can either upload the icon sprites to your own server or change the URLs in the style-sheet to point to the jQuery CDN.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem

But that is the thing they are uploaded to my own server, in this map
http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1-theme/images/ 

tTat is why it drives me nuts, i can't figure out why it isn't working

Comment: @DaveZegers The `404` errors I posted show that you have uploaded them to the wrong directory... They need to be located in a directory named `images` that is the direct sub-directory of the directory that holds the CSS style-sheet you got from Themeroller.

Comment: Thanks Jasper you where right, i could not figure out what was wrong but then it hit me when i added the url's you posted into my browser and saw that iondead there was no imagefolder in teh css map with the sprites

How a stupid simple litle like thing can cost you all day :)

Thanks